# Show/Hide UL child if checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, checkbox

I'm trying to show/hide some ul checkboxes when the parent is clicked. I've searched everywhere and I just can't get it to work!

Could someone please help me to get this to work? If a parent category is checked, sub checkboxes needs to show/hide.

This is the code:

```html
<div id="refine-categories">
      <h4>Categories</h4>
      <ul class="parent cf">
<li id='project_category-3' class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="3" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-3" /> Aanbouw &amp; Opbouw</label><ul class='children'>

<li id='project_category-33'><label class="selectit"><input value="33" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-33" /> aanbouw</label></li>

<li id='project_category-34'><label class="selectit"><input value="34" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-34" /> algemeen</label></li>

<li id='project_category-35'><label class="selectit"><input value="35" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-35" /> Fundering en heiwerken</label></li>

<li id='project_category-36'><label class="selectit"><input value="36" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-36" /> garage bouwen</label></li>

<li id='project_category-37'><label class="selectit"><input value="37" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-37" /> isoleren</label></li>

<li id='project_category-38'><label class="selectit"><input value="38" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-38" /> nieuwbouw</label></li>

<li id='project_category-39'><label class="selectit"><input value="39" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-39" /> opbouw</label></li>

<li id='project_category-40'><label class="selectit"><input value="40" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-40" /> renovatie</label></li>

<li id='project_category-41'><label class="selectit"><input value="41" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-41" /> veranda en serre</label></li>
</li>
</ul>     </div>
```

When I click on a parent checkbox I can see the span class is changed to `<span class="custom checkbox checked"></span>`

Hope someone can help me to sort this out!

Thank you for your time!

PS: You can check the website here: http://bit.ly/20Miaom It's in the sidebar (right).

Comment: please remember to accept one of the answers if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use some JQuery for this.

```
$('#in-project_category-3').click(function () {
    $(".children").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

while your child ul needs to get `display: none`

I made you a fiddle, i hope this is what you wanted:
https://jsfiddle.net/jfuhdq0g/2/

Comment: The sample on Fiddle works great! But when adding the JQuery to the website nothing happens? Am I putting it in a wrong file maybe? Also in  your sample you call #in-project_category-3. But on the website there are more parents. So the next parent would be category 8.? How can I get this to show/hide too? 

I am really happy with your sample! Can't wait to get it all fixed haha. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I updated the fiddle, if you want some more id to have the same effect you just add some more lines of code like now shown in the fiddle. Well if it is not working i could imagine that maybe you have included the JQuery the wrong way (is the jquery repository included in the head of your website?) or you have forgotten to give the ul class="children a display: none like shown in my fiddle. Note that if you use this method every children ul should have an unique class, otherwise all children would get opened on click at one of the parental li`s.

Comment: Hi Marcel, Thank you for helping. I just can't get it to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Could you please have a look at the website? And help me out?  http://bit.ly/20Miaom

Comment: Well, the console tells me "$ is not a function"... Have you included JQuery to the header of your website?

Answer (score 0):

set the `.children` to `display:none;`.

then from `.parent`, find the first checkbox. add a `change` event then `toggle` `.children` if it is checked.

to be more generic for all lists, use `this`, go back up the the `.parent` and find the `.children` to toggle.

```
$('.parent input[type="checkbox"]:first-child').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```js
$('.parent input[type="checkbox"]:first-child').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent').find('.children').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```css
.children {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refine-categories">
  <h4>Categories</h4>
  <ul class="parent cf">
    <li id='project_category-3' class="popular-category">
      <label class="selectit">
        <input value="3" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-3" />Aanbouw &amp; Opbouw</label>
      <ul class='children'>

        <li id='project_category-33'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="33" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-33" />aanbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-34'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="34" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-34" />algemeen</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-35'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="35" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-35" />Fundering en heiwerken</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-36'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="36" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-36" />garage bouwen</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-37'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="37" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-37" />isoleren</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-38'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="38" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-38" />nieuwbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-39'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="39" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-39" />opbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-40'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="40" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-40" />renovatie</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-41'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="41" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-41" />veranda en serre</label>
        </li>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="refine-categories">
  <h4>Categories 2</h4>
  <ul class="parent cf">
    <li id='project_category-3' class="popular-category">
      <label class="selectit">
        <input value="3" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-3" />Aanbouw &amp; Opbouw</label>
      <ul class='children'>

        <li id='project_category-33'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="33" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-33" />aanbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-34'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="34" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-34" />algemeen</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-35'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="35" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-35" />Fundering en heiwerken</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-36'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="36" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-36" />garage bouwen</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-37'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="37" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-37" />isoleren</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-38'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="38" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-38" />nieuwbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-39'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="39" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-39" />opbouw</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-40'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="40" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-40" />renovatie</label>
        </li>

        <li id='project_category-41'>
          <label class="selectit">
            <input value="41" type="checkbox" name="cat_project_category[]" id="in-project_category-41" />veranda en serre</label>
        </li>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```